# Equivalent for BindingList<T>.ListChanged event in android

Tags: android, inotifypropertychanged

I want to observe property changed event of a list of object and observe list change (item added/removed) as well. In .NET I can use `BindingList<T>` in conjunction with `INotifyPropertyChanged` event and consume `ListChanged` event. I would like to know how to implement this in android with api 14.

**Note**: using `Observe Design Pattern` for each item in the list is out of option, because this list is huge, and will consume much time to setup observer for each item

Comment: Overriding the list implementation to insert the listener logic in the target methods(like add/remove etc) isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: It just solve one part of the problem, the other part is observe property changed of item in that list

Comment: First, I'm not familiar with .NET, did changing the field of the list object will also trigger that event? In the overridden add() methods of the list you could make a binding of the list to the object(pass the list reference). In the object you could then implement the logic to observe the change in properties and forward the event to the list.

Comment: @Luksprog `ListChanged` event in .NET will trigger an event whenever any changes occur in the list like: new item added, item removed, property of an object in that list is modified... etc. I'll try with your suggestion and give you feedback, thank for your advice